# Backbone-relational not setting parent model, or reverse relation _id

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

In this app, an incident is something that happened, and a feeling is a nested object that describes how you felt about it.  Here's my Incident model:

```
window.Incident = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

urlRoot: "/incidents",

idAttribute: "_id",

relations:[{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'feelings',
    relatedModel: 'Feeling',
    reverseRelation: {
        key: 'incident',
        includeInJSON: '_id'
    }
},
{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'thoughts',
    relatedModel: 'window.Thought',
    reverseRelation: {
        key: 'incident',
        includeInJSON: '_id'
    }
}],
 // rest of model...
});
```

And here is the Feeling model:

```
window.Feeling = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  urlRoot: '/incidents',
  idAttribute: '_id'
});
```

At this point, I can CRUD incidents, and also feelings.  But, feelings are not being assigned the reverse relation.  In a feeling, the attribute 'incident' is given the value 'null'.  In my MongoDB collection, I get these two unrelated objects:

```
{ "description" : "I feel sad", "_id" : ObjectId("50d3b1462ff17f07cf000002") }
{ "name" : "asdf", "intensityBefore" : "asdf", "intensityAfter" : "asdf", "incident" : null, "_id" : ObjectId("50d3b14e2ff17f07cf000003") }
```

I have the full project up at https://github.com/mhurwi/cbt-app/tree/relational.

Note, this app is built off a starter app by Christophe Coenraets:  https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar

It's been many hours now, and I cannot understand why the relationship is not being set by backbone-relational.

Comment: Would help if you could reproduce is in a jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to declare BackboneRelational.HasOne on the Feelings model, like so:

```
window.Feeling = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    urlRoot: '/incidents',
    idAttribute: '_id',
    relations:[{
        type: Backbone.HasOne,
        key: 'incident',
        relatedModel: 'Incident'
    }]
});
```